# How can I resize a XAML TextBox at runtime through user interaction?

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'd like to know if it's possible to resize a XAML `TextBox` during runtime, and through user interaction. That is, the user uses handlebars to manually resize the `TextBox` as needed. Although the `TextBox` seems to have a `sizeChanged` event, I can't figure out how can I possibly change the size manually at runtime.

Comment: Why can't you set the width and height at runtime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resizing a control in Windows store app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607618/resizing-a-control-in-windows-store-app)

Comment: Usually, it's considered polite to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the XAML to create the effect:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyTextBox" Width="250"
        MinWidth="250" MinHeight="60"
        Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Polygon">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <CompositeTransform TranslateX="5" TranslateY="5" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5" />
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeDisabledLowBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Thumb">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <CompositeTransform TranslateX="10" TranslateY="10" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBox Header="First Name" Text="Jerry" />
    <Thumb DoubleTapped="GrabDoubleTapped" DragDelta="GrabDelta" Loaded="GrabLoaded" />
    <Polygon Points="0,19 19,0, 19,19" />
</Grid>
```

And here's the code-behind to handle it:

```
Windows.Foundation.Size originalSize;
private void GrabLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    originalSize = MyTextBox.RenderSize;
}

private void GrabDelta(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    MyTextBox.Width = MyTextBox.ActualWidth + e.HorizontalChange;
    MyTextBox.Height = MyTextBox.ActualHeight + e.VerticalChange;
}

private void GrabDoubleTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyTextBox.Height = originalSize.Height;
    MyTextBox.Width = originalSize.Width;
}
```

You could easily wrap this into a control or user control or something. Sure.

Looks like this:

[image]

Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

Ahmad,

There are 2 solutions I have for you.

**Solution 1:**

A simple, upfront solution could be using the **grid splitters** which helps you in dragging & resizing the control. The number of grid splitters depends on the way you want the TextBox to be resized. Below is a code sample:

```
<Grid>...
<GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ResizeDirection="Rows" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="4" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="Transparent"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="6,6,6,6" Name="RequestTextBox" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Request, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<GridSplitter Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ResizeDirection="Rows" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="4" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="Transparent"/>
...</Grid>
```

Note: You might as well put 4 Grid splitters to resize the textbox from 4 directions but a heads up, that you may have to define DragCompleted event on the GridSplitter(s) to adjust widths & heights.

**Solution 2:**

Also you could do this with an **Adorner**. Below is a four-part series on that topic without and with Adorners:

P.S: I haven't summarised what the links convey, since the topic is itself so vast. Hence advise you to check the links. Just in case the links go dead, googling Adorners shouldn't be too tough ;)

- [Part-1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx)
- [Part-2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part2.aspx)
- [Part-3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part3.aspx)
- [Part-4](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx)

Comment: Only WPF has adorners, not the WinRT.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: My bad. Would the grid splitter solution help?

Comment: It too doesn't address the original request. In only the simplest of UI would it work.